# Make a program that prints its own size

Tags: code-golf, self-referential

**Challenge:** Create a program that prints out the size of its own source code file.

For example, a 35 bytes size of program must print out 35. **Pre-calculation** is not valid. What I mean by pre-calculation is:

```
 // test.js -> its size is 15 byte
 console.log(15)
```

**It must dynamically calculate the size of  own source code file.**
The winner is who prints the minimum number , same as who has the minimum size of code.

Comment: Em, `console.log(15)` is valid?

Comment: Well it is not a good solution, if you calculate first and print :), pre-calculation is not valid.

Comment: You should set some rules for cases like that so

Comment: The program should dynamically calculate its own length then? You should mention such rules as part of the question (And have you seen the "[Sandbox for Proposed Challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges)"? You can post your questions there first and get help making them clearer and more likely to yield useful, interesting answers.)

Comment: Yes it must be dynamically. thanks for advice, I will get help there to make it clear.

Comment: Do you mean by reading the size of its source file or were you thinking of some other means?

Comment: @Neil , I mean the size of the source code.

Comment: [Possible duplicate.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/121056/41024)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder *It must dynamically calculate the size of own source code file.*

Comment: Is not "reading the source code file and count the bytes" the only form of "dynamically calculate" possible? I feel that "calculate" gives the impression we can somehow work out how big the source code is from some other values.

Comment: *calculate* can also mean *enumerate*, i.e. to count.

Comment: Can the program contain the name of its own source file?

Comment: So...? Anything that would count as "reading your own source code" and invalid for normal quine challenge is valid here?

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Your challenge has been put on hold. It means it can be reopen once clarification questions have been addressed. I do have one such question: usually programs and functions are allowed, do you allow functions?

Comment: So, is `print(2*5)` considered dynamic calculate?

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 10 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
≢⊃⌽⎕NR⊃⎕SI
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94P@jzkWPupof9ex91DfVLwjE7Jsa7AmS@68ABgUA) Prints 11 because TIO's APL is set up to auto-format the code, but on a system where this isn't the case, it prints 10:

[image: Session]

`⎕SI` **S**tate **I**ndicator (list of all functions on the stack)

`⊃` pick the first one (i.e. the currently running function)

`⎕NR` **N**ested **R**epresentation (one character list per line)

`⌽` reverse (to bring the actual code line to the front)

`⊃` pick the first (i.e. the code line)

`≢` tally the characters of that

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 32 bytes

Not much to say really, opens the file and checks the length of its contents as a string.

```
print(len([*open(__file__)][0]))
```

There might be something shorter but I couldn't think of it.

*Edit: [Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EIyc1TyNaK78ASMXHp2XmpMbHa8ZGG8Rqav7/DwA) (stolen from the comments - thanks for the reminder!)*

Comment: Was just typing these exact characters lol, you can remove one byte from print by switching to python2, provided it doesn't break the rest

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if [*x] works in Python 2 - I don't have an install to test it, but if it does work then yes, you could save one :)

Comment: `[*...]` does not work in Python 2, but `print len(open(__file__).read())` does for 32 bytes as well.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EIyc1TyNaK78ASMXHp2XmpMbHa8ZGG8Rqav7/DwA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Why only the first line (`[0]`)?

Comment: ...[i.e.TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EIyc1TyNaK78ASMXHp2XmpMbHa8ZGG8RqanJBFCiFZGQWKxRn5JfmpKiXpSqARVNTFMzMlTT//wcA)

Comment: Making it work for all lines takes a fair few more bytes since you have to do something like `print(sum(len(x)for x in[*open(__file__)]))` instead, but the source _is_ only one line so that isn't necessary (the question didn't say it had to adapt to additional source being added). [Example](https://tio.run/##FchBDgIhDAXQvaf4iRtw6wk8hzEEh05ogi2Bjsx4edTNW7x6WFa5znnGLSWMHI3e1HDohhHFECXBMqHzhzC4FHT7@yQs2hotdqqNxVzfXq6QuN2v2rCD5X7R@osQVi4Ugn94P@cX)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>40</s> 20 bytes

*-20 thanks to @Shaggy*

```javascript
f=_=>("f="+f).length
```

```js
f=_=>("f="+f).length

alert(f())
```

Comment: `f=_=>("f="+f).length`

Comment: ... Because this is valid for normal quine challenge, it's invalid here? ... Also why not just `2+`?

Comment: @user202729 but `2+(''+f).length` do not save a byte